# How to set up google analytics (or Firebase Analytics) in electron desktop app?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-analytics, electron, firebase-analytics

I want to collect the data of desktop app built with electron
I created the property(app+web) in firebase console then get the Firebase SDK snippet as below:

```
<!-- The core Firebase JS SDK is always required and must be listed first -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.0/firebase-app.js"></script>

<!-- TODO: Add SDKs for Firebase products that you want to use
     https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup#available-libraries -->
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.9.0/firebase-analytics.js"></script>

<script>
  // Your web app's Firebase configuration
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "xxxxxxxxx",
    authDomain: "xxxxxxx.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "xxxxxxxxx",
    projectId: "xxxxxxx",
    storageBucket: "xxxxxxxxx",
    messagingSenderId: "xxxxxx",
    appId: "xxxxxxxxx",
    measurementId: "G-xxxxxxxx"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
  firebase.analytics();
</script>
```

put the configuration into the body section then try to send the logEvent
unfortunately i cannot see any stream data in real-time data collection
Any thought would be appricated.

Comment: for now i just open a invisible iframe and send data to firebase console through other website, and it works

Comment: can you please explain?

Comment: @Vitto_tredue  i create the simple webpage just to send data to the firebase console, and in desktop app, i open that webpage in an invisible iframe  everytime i need to collect the data. It is a bit stupid, but it work though

Comment: zyo zyo are you sending events from electron into that iframe? How? Url query string parameters?